# Can I put 12 V LED lights into a USB to be plugged into a USB power bank?

Tags: led, usb

I'm doing a project for school and I'm going to be making a 3D print nano gauntlet from end game. I want to put some LED lights into it but I'm just trying to figure out for easy access if I can hook up all the LEDs into a USB port so I can just a USB power bank into it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

They don't even need to be 12V lights: 5V ones are fine. In fact you can buy LED strings that are USB powered with the connector built-in, but you can also convert LED strings that use three 1.5V batteries to USB power very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Leds themselves are not 12v or 5v. Simple leds have a ballast resistor set for a given current at a given input voltage.

You could use an led string or strip made for 5v instead of 12v, with pretty much any usb power bank. Keep in mind some power banks have an auto shutoff if the current drawn is too low.

If you really need to use the 12v strip, you have two options. Newer power banks tend to have fancier features like QC or USB PD. Some can provide 12V internally, with those protocols, if you use a USB PD trigger board, a module that tells the power bank to output 12V with a handshake. The other option is to use an external step up/boost converter. Both options are small and cheap.

Just test before you go out with it that the power bank doesn't fall asleep because you aren't drawing enough power.